# Storybook config in typescript

Tags: typescript, config, storybook

I would like to write storybook decorator. Is there any way to write it and `preview.js` in typescript?

I already succeeded in writing stories itself in TS, and now would like to write storybook config in TS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally manage to make it works.

- Configs directory should be added to include option of typescript preset and tsconfig.json
- Set module resolution to "node", because for some reasons it got set to "classic" for config folder

Also, `main.js` should stay JS file, because only after parsing `main.js` config, storybook able to use TS preset.

Comment: Please clarify "Configs directory should be added to include option of typescript preset and tsconfig.json". What did you change exactly and where?

Comment: Update: this works for me, including `main.ts` in the latest storybook@6.3.

Comment: @jorisw He meant there is a include option inside `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 23):

Since storybook 6.3, you can write `main.ts` and `preview.ts` in typescript.
[See the example in the 6.3.0 release here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/v6.3.0/examples/cra-ts-kitchen-sink/.storybook).

> **Note:** If you use a newer version than 6.3.0, change the tag filter in the repository link above to match and locate a similar example in case the syntax has changed.

However, the caveat here is that you cannot use `{"target": "ESNext"}` in your typical `tsconfig.json` because node doesn't support ES module natively, yet.

If you want ESNext, for example using storybook alongside `rollup`, a workaround is needed. My approach is to configure storybook to use another `tsconfig.json` via the environment variable `TS_NODE_PROJECT`. For example

.storybook/tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "..",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2017"
  }
}
```

Then run `cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=.storybook/tsconfig.json start-storybook`.

The reason it works because storybook uses webpack which in turn using `tsconfig-paths` to resolve the path for `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Good one on tsconfig-paths and TS_NODE_PROJECT.

Comment: You can also add

```
"tsnode":{
  compilerOptions: {
    module: 'commonjs',
  },
}
```

to your tsconfig.json, and then it should work without setting TS_NODE_PROJECT (telling storybook which tsconfig.json to use manually).

Answer (score 4):

Since `v6.5` simply import the type and create a configuration object.

```
// .storybook/main.ts

import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react/types';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
    ...
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: for builder vite you import like this: `import type {StorybookViteConfig} from "@storybook/builder-vite";`

Comment: Turns out you can just rename your files to `preview.ts` and `main.ts`, and they'll continue to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

To use TypeScript for your config files, change them to `main.ts` and `preview.ts` and then create `.storybook/.babelrc` and add the following:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-your-project-with-typescript

Note: [there is a bug](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19192) that breaks `npm run storybook` if the `ts-node` package exists anywhere in your dependency tree.